# Date Function for DB2

Tags: db2

I have a file which has transaction details in DB2 and my requirement is extract last 1 months transaction data. Currently I amend the date range manually as bellow.

**WHERE TRAN_DATE BETWEEN 20170115 and 20170214**

Is there a way to code without manually adjusting the dates daily?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `current date` and date arithmetics?

```
WHERE TRAN_DATE BETWEEN current date and (current date - 1 month)
```

If you need the `YYYYMMDD` format, you can convert like this:

```
YEAR(CURRENT DATE) * 10000 + MONTH(CURRENT DATE) * 100 + DAY(CURRENT DATE)
```

Comment: You think it will be compatible with the date format in my file? Date is populated as YYYYMMDD

Comment: @ShabeenZarook No, but you can create a UDF that converts a date value to a numeric value.  You don't mention a platform, but if IBM i, consider downloading and using [Alan Campin's iDate](http://www.think400.dk/downloads.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If TRANS_DATE is a number then

```
WHERE TRANS_DATE BETWEEN INTEGER(TO_CHAR(CURRENT DATE,'YYYYMMDD')) AND 
                         INTEGER(TO_CHAR(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH,'YYYYMMDD'))
```

If it is a string then

```
WHERE TRANS_DATE BETWEEN TO_CHAR(CURRENT DATE,'YYYYMMDD') AND 
                         TO_CHAR(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH,'YYYYMMDD')
```