# DB2- select rows with date_column of last month

Tags: db2

I need to select count(field) from table where the date_column is within the last month, i.e. from the first of the last month till the first of this month. As this query will be automated it will need to refer to the last month of any given day.

Also the date_column has a datatype of timestamp

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any research you did? Any SQL query you can show?

Comment: Anything i've managed to find uses the current date, which will continually change.  I also tried a function yesterday and failed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254419/date-function-for-db2/42255494#42255494

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date Function for DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254419/date-function-for-db2)

Comment: I would require data from the first of the last month till the first of this month

Answer (score 0):

SELECT (CAST(current timestamp AS DATE)) - (DAY(CAST(current timestamp AS DATE)) - 1)DAYS FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;

SELECT (CAST(current timestamp AS DATE)) - (DAY(CAST(current timestamp AS DATE)) - 1)DAYS 
- 1 MONTH
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;

Managed to find these queries, to find the first of this month and last month